# Echo command in makefile printing in wrong order

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following Makefile, with a rule which checks for dependencies:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

dependencies:
    $(info START-info)
    @echo "START-echo"
    $(call assert-command-present,fastqc)
    $(call assert-command-present,cutadapt)
    $(call assert-command-present,bowtie2)
    $(call assert-command-present,samtools)
    $(call assert-command-present,bedtools)
    $(call assert-command-present,fetchChromSizes)
    $(call assert-command-present,bedGraphToBigWig)
    $(info END-info)
    @echo "END-echo"

pipeline: dependencies

assert-command-present = $(info Checking for $1) && $(if $(shell which $1),$(info OK.),$(error ERROR: could not find '$1'. Exiting))
```

The user-defined function assert-command-present checks for a command in the path, and returns an error if it is not found. When I run this Makefile, the echo and info commands are not returned in the order I expect:

```
START-info
Checking for fastqc
OK.
Checking for cutadapt
OK.
Checking for bowtie2
OK.
Checking for samtools
OK.
Checking for bedtools
OK.
Checking for fetchChromSizes
OK.
Checking for bedGraphToBigWig
OK.
END-info
START-echo
END-echo
```

The START-echo and START-info commands should run before any assert-command-presents functions run, but the echo command runs after the function calls.

Comment: It seems like `make` evaluates its `info` and `warning` functions earlier than the `echo` calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eugeniu Rosca is correct. More generally, "make" built-in functions are evaluated first, then the entire command sequence is run.

One way to see this is to use the GNU make debugger [remake](https://bashdb.sf.net/remake). You can stop at the target "dependencies", and write out the commands that would be run in a shell.

For example:

```
 $ remake -X -f /tmp/Makefile dependencies
 GNU Make 4.1+dbg0.91
 ...
 Updating goal targets....
 -> (/tmp/Makefile:3)
 dependencies: 
 remake<0> write
 START-info
 END-info
 File "/tmp/dependencies.sh" written.
 remake<1>
```

Look at file `/tmp/dependencies.sh` and you will see all of the Make functions removed or expanded with whatever value they returned which in my case was empty lines.

Comment: As an aside, is the way I have concatenated the two function calls into a single user-defined function correct?

Comment: "correct" is a very loaded term, and even without that I am not totally sure what code you are talking about. But you can check things yourself, by going again into remake at the target that you want to check ("break *targetname*) and then use the "expand" command to evaluate whatever expression you want.